# pandas: records with lists to separate rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, split

I have a Python Pandas DataFrame like this (UCSC schema for NCBI RefSeq):

```
chrom   exonStart     exonEnds      name
chr1    100,200,300   110,210,310   gen1
chr1    500,700       600,800       gen2
chr2    50,60,70,80   55,65,75,85   gen3
```

and I'd like to pair values from exonStarts and exonEnds and put them as separate rows (keeping the rest of corresponding information):

```
chrom   exonStart     exonEnds      name
chr1    100           110           gen1
chr1    200           210           gen1
chr1    300           310           gen1
chr1    500           600           gen2
chr1    700           800           gen2
chr2    50            55            gen3
chr2    60            65            gen3
chr2    70            75            gen3
chr2    80            85            gen3
```

I was thinking to use combinations of python/pandas functions as:

> zip, split, melt, concat

but somehow it doesn't work for me

Comment: show your approach first

Comment: pd.DataFrame(list(zip(df['exonStarts'][0].split(',')[:-1], df['exonEnds'][0].split(',')[:-1]))) in a loop etc.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `zip` and `split` within a comprehension

```
pd.DataFrame([
    [c, s, e, n]
    for c, S, E, n in df.itertuples(index=False)
    for s, e in zip(S.split(','), E.split(','))
], columns=df.columns)

  chrom exonStart exonEnds  name
0  chr1       100      110  gen1
1  chr1       200      210  gen1
2  chr1       300      310  gen1
3  chr1       500      600  gen2
4  chr1       700      800  gen2
5  chr2        50       55  gen3
6  chr2        60       65  gen3
7  chr2        70       75  gen3
8  chr2        80       85  gen3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way using `numpy` and `intertools.chain`.

The idea is to first split your comma separated fields into lists. Then construct a results dataframe, repeating or chaining values were necessary.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

df['exonStart'] = df['exonStart'].str.split(',')
df['exonEnds'] = df['exonEnds'].str.split(',')

lens = list(map(len, df['exonStart']))

res = pd.DataFrame({'chrom': np.repeat(df['chrom'], lens),
                    'exonStart': list(chain.from_iterable(df['exonStart'])),
                    'exonEnds': list(chain.from_iterable(df['exonEnds'])),
                    'name': np.repeat(df['name'], lens)})

print(res)

#   chrom exonEnds exonStart  name
# 0  chr1      110       100  gen1
# 0  chr1      210       200  gen1
# 0  chr1      310       300  gen1
# 1  chr1      600       500  gen2
# 1  chr1      800       700  gen2
# 2  chr2       55        50  gen3
# 2  chr2       65        60  gen3
# 2  chr2       75        70  gen3
# 2  chr2       85        80  gen3
```

Note you may wish to convert your numeric columns to `int` at the end of this process.

Answer (score 1):

I come up with this , by using`unstack` and `stack`

```
df.set_index(['chrom','name']).apply(lambda x : x.str.split(','),1).\
   stack().apply(pd.Series).stack().unstack(-2).\
       reset_index().drop('level_2',1)
Out[1201]: 
  chrom  name exonStart exonEnds
0  chr1  gen1       100      110
1  chr1  gen1       200      210
2  chr1  gen1       300      310
3  chr1  gen2       500      600
4  chr1  gen2       700      800
5  chr2  gen3        50       55
6  chr2  gen3        60       65
7  chr2  gen3        70       75
8  chr2  gen3        80       85
```