# How to split column values of a panda data frame into rows separated by “,”

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am trying to separate the column values separated by "," separator of a panda dataframe.

The original data Original panda dataframe

[image]

The desired output Desired output

[image]

I have tried several ways.

Explode/stack a Series of strings

```
newdf['Month'] = newdf['Month'].apply(list)
```

using the above code I am getting `[j,a,n,,f,e,b]` and then I have used

```
pd.Dataframe({'Month':np.concatenate(newdf['Month'].values), 'cust.no':newdf['cust.no'].repeat(newdf['cust no.'].apply(len))})
```

The output is each letter is coming in separate rows. As a result, the row numbers are not matching with "cust no." and I am getting error.

I know there are several functions available but I couldn't one that can efficiently break down the values.

Comment: You posted this question earlier today.  It was, and still is, a duplicate.  Either way, in the future, please post dataframes as images, not text

Comment: The below link has solved my problem. Very very useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50082449/splitting-multiple-columns-on-a-delimiter-into-rows-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can always just use a regex (regular expression) to identify all text before the comma.

Assuming your original dataframe is called `data`, meaning your months column is `data['Months']`, you can use the regular expression `r'(.+?),'` to select everything before the comma.

```
data['Months'] = data['Months'].str.extract(r'(.+?),', expand=True)
```

You can always test regex at https://pythex.org/. Try entering your months column in the test string box, and `(.+?),` as the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

#### `Setup`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4], 'month': ['Jan,Fev', 'Feb,July', 'Jun,Aug', 'July,Mar']})

    id  month
0   1   Jan,Fev
1   2   Feb,July
2   3   Jun,Aug
3   4   July,Mar
```

#### `str.split`+`pd.DataFrame()`+`stack`

```
df = df.set_index('id')
pd.DataFrame(df.month.str.split(',').to_dict()).T.stack().reset_index(level=0, name='month')

    level_0 month
0   1       Jan
1   1       Fev
0   2       Feb
1   2       July
0   3       Jun
1   3       Aug
0   4       July
1   4       Mar
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to do on all the columns at one time otherwise I am getting error due to not matching row numbers. So, I am using the following code pd.DataFrame(new.apply(lambda x: x.to_dict("series").str.split(",").T.stack().reset_index(),axis=1,raw = False)).   However, I am getting this error- ("unsupported type: <class 'str'>", . Would you like to share your thoughts.